compiling shared php-module as dll (windows)
i'm trying to compile a shared extension for php 8.3.6 x64 for windows
i basicly followed these instructions: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/804/how-to-compile-a-php-extension-dll-file-in-windows-with-visual-studio#disqus_thread
Problem: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mailparse.dll' (tried: ./ext\php_mailparse.dll (Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden)) in Unknown on line 0
so what did i do:

installed basic components of Visual Studio 2019
create folder c:\php-sdk
extracted php-source from https://www.php.net/distributions/php-8.3.6.tar.gz into php-sdk
extracted contents of https://pecl.php.net/get/mailparse-3.1.6.tgz to php-sdk/ext/mailparse
as of instructions i should run buildconf and configure, what it said binary tools are missing, so
downloaded https://github.com/php/php-sdk-binary-tools and extracted to php-sdk/php-sdk-binary-tools-master
open vs command prompt
goto php-sdk/php-sdk-binary-tools-master
run phpsdk-vs16-x64.bat
go back to php-sdk
run configure --disable-all --enable-cli --enable-mbstring --enable-mailparse --disable-zts --with-all-shared
output:

-----------------------
| Extension  | Mode   |
-----------------------
...
| mailparse  | shared |
...
-----------------------


Enabled SAPI:
-------------
| Sapi Name |
-------------
| cli       |
-------------

-----------------------------------------
| Build type          | Release         |
| Thread Safety       | No              |
| Compiler            | Visual C++ 2019 |
| Target Architecture | x64             |
| Host Architecture   | x64             |
| Optimization        | PGO disabled    |
| Native intrinsics   | SSE2            |
| Static analyzer     | disabled        |
-----------------------------------------


run nmake

now in php-sdk\x64\Release i found a php_mailparse.dll,
[edit] and copied it to the ext-folder of the precompiled php-binaries, [/edit] but this dll gives me the error written at the beginning ... anybody know what i've done wrong?

now in php-sdk\x64\Release i found a php_mailparse.dll <--> tried: ./ext\php_mailparse.dll.  Are they the same folder?

ah yes of course i copied it to the ext-folder of the php-binaries

./ext is a relative path, Can you confirm that you are running PHP in the folder where this ext file is located? If you are unsure, it is recommended that you use an absolute path.

to clarify this: its in the same folder all other loaded and working extensions are located, it also does not say, that the file cannot be found, it says, that the procedure can not be found

tried again with the instructions at https://github.com/jhanley-com/php-ssh2-windows/blob/master/BUILD-SSH2.md with no luck

I tried this instruction: https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild_sdk_2#building_pecl_extensions and it succeeded. The source code need to be placed in x64/pecl/.

it works now!
done as you said, but it still did not work. since mailparse depends on mbstring, i also compiled mbstring=shared and replaced the precompiled php_mbstring.dll (1554kb) with the new compiled one (1058kb) and now phpinfo shows loaded mailparse ;)

thanks to @shingo and a little experiment i got it working, as @shingo posted in his comment compiling shared php-module as dll (windows) i've done the following based on the instructions of https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild_sdk_2#building_pecl_extensions
i have installed Visual Studio Community 2019 with the following components (i don't know which one a really needed, just glad it worked overall ^^)

Desktopdevelopment with C++



MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ -x64/x86Buildtools
Windows 10 SDK
Just-In-Time-Debugger
C++-Profilingtools
C++-CMake-Tools for Windows
C++ AddressSanitizer



download php source from https://windows.php.net/download/ (example https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-8.3.6-src.zip)
download php binary tools from https://github.com/php/php-sdk-binary-tools
download pecl extension src from https://pecl.php.net/package/mailparse

now:

create folder C:\php-sdk

extract php-source to C:\php-sdk (now i had the php source in C:\php-sdk\php-8.3.6-src)

extract contents php-sdk-binary-tools-master.zip\php-sdk-binary-tools-master to C:\php-sdk (so that for exmaple phpsdk-vs16-x64.bat will be in C:\php-sdk)

go into php-src-folder (C:\php-sdk\php-8.3.6-src in my case) and create a folder "pecl"

extract src of extension to C:\php-sdk\php-8.3.6-src\pecl (in my case mailparse, so i had a folder C:\php-sdk\php-8.3.6-src\pecl\pecl-mail-mailparse-master, but i renamed it to C:\php-sdk\php-8.3.6-src\pecl\mailparse)


now open command prompt:

cd C:\php-sdk
phpsdk-vs16-x64.bat
cd php-8.3.6-src
buildconf
configure --disable-all --enable-cli --enable-mbstring=shared --enable-mailparse=shared --disable-zts (--disable-zts because i'm compiling for fastcgi under iis, also --enable-mbstring=shared was necessary, since mailparse depends on mbstring, without it, it did not work)
nmake

now i copied php_mbstring.dll and php_mailparse.dll from C:\php-sdk\php-8.3.6-src\x64\Release to the extension-folder of my running prebuild php-binaries ext-folder, REPLACING the existing php_mbstring.dll and now it works ;)
